# installed via bitnami

Tags: django

i've had some strange errors when trying to install django
standalone, so i have used the whole bundle option, linked from
documentation. Bitnami. It installed python, django, apache,
sqlite.... I use Windows XP btw.

And i've went first run on python and django by the tutorial.
Unfortunatly i have stopped at part 2 when i should login to admin
panel, and can't solve problem with css and js files. They just don't
load, do a 404 and i see admin panel in a pure html layout (scary).

So how could i fix this?
My settings.py and urls.py are all default, except i turned on all
those apps that tutorial said to and admin url.

I see that the css and js files lies in their folders under this path:

> C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\contrib\admin
>   \media

While my app(models, views,tests) is here:

> C:\Documents and Settings\Luka\BitNami DjangoStack projects\djangoTut
>   \polls

and settings.py is one folder up

How should i configure and what to make those damn css load?

Answer (score 0):

Well, simply put, read here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/#serving-files

You have to(see doc):

> Create a symbolic link to the admin static files from within your
>   document root. Or, copy the admin static files so that they live
>   within your Apache document root.

and fiddle your apache/nginx configuration a bit!

To give you an example with my config, but btw, I'm not using django 1.3 ... so no `django.contrib.staticfiles`. But the differences aren't that big:

Apache:

```
<Directory "D:/projects/my_project/src">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /my_project D:/projects/my_project/src/django.wsgi

Alias /media/ "D:/projects/my_project/media/"
Alias /static-media/ "D:/projects/my_project/media-static/"

<DirectoryMatch "D:/projects/my_project/media/">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</DirectoryMatch>
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'D:/projects/my_project/media/'
STATIC_MEDIA_URL = '/static-media/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/static-media/admin/'
```

Now you either copy the admin static files to the defined static-media location, or you symlink it! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885/how-to-create-symbolic-links-in-windows, but you probably end up copying!

Usefull link, if you enjoy reading:

1. http://www.muhuk.com/2009/05/serving-static-media-in-django-development-server/
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

Also, instead of creating symbolic links you can point the Alias in the apache configuration file directly to the django files:

```
Alias /static-media/ "C:\Program Files\BitNami DjangoStack\apps\django\django\contrib\admin \media"
```

If you installed the latest version of BitNami Django Stack (I'm a BitNami developer and we recently released a fix for something related to this), and you selected to create a default project you can take a look at the .wsgi file for that project.